# installing appcelerator titanium on ubuntu server

Tags: android, ubuntu, titanium, appcelerator

I'm having problems running app developed in appcelerator on an Ubuntu server. I install all the necessary software (node, npp, appcelerator, android sdk, java) bun when I run appc run and select android, I receive this error: [ERROR] Unable to find platform configuration for "android".
This is the result of the ti config command (the ones conerning android):

```
android.ndkPath        = "/home/user/android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64.bin/android-ndk-r13b"
android.sdkPath        = "/home/user/android-sdk"
app.workspace          = "/home/user"
```

If I run ti setup and check the environment all the tests are passed, marked with a green check mark.
Did anyone encounter the same problem, or can anyone point me into the right direction.

Cheers

Comment: could your post your `ti info` output please

Comment: I added 2 screenshots since it's a large output

https://www.dropbox.com/s/c49hz6pcd4j424n/Screen%20Shot%202016-12-29%20at%2001.45.28.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/id5ouedj1693uw7/Screen%20Shot%202016-12-29%20at%2001.46.14.png?dl=0

Comment: Strange. It says it doesn't find Ti SDK newer than 3.2 Below the Virtualbox info (but you have 6.0.1.GA installed). And Android NDK is empty, plus I have a link to `ADB Executable` inside the `Android SDK` block, that is missing in your screenshot, too. Perheps you need to reinstall. Make sure to check http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK